# One of application build remove GraphQl 'query' field

Tags: javascript, https, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have Apollo graphQl front application. This application is building by webpack to static js files.

In dev version of code everything works fine. In prod version on `http` nginx server all works too. All queries look like:
[image]

But I have another prod version. There is only one difference between production versions: This one works on `https`.
And queries from this version sending without 'query' field.

[image]

Do you have any suppose, why graphQl loose 'query' field?

P.S js files have the same content. I have compared symbol by symbol

Comment: try to debug it on the problematic env

Comment: What did you mean? Must I look at environment variables on nginx container? But this variables can't influence on static js files.

Comment: I mean put a debugger break point on the moment it sends the request and check if all the params are ok

Comment: can't put a break point, because there is minimizated code. But problem has resolved. Thank you for answer. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in deployment's scripts. Our DevOps wrote something like this:

```
sed -i "s/http:/https:/g" $file;
```

Of course this code was breaking some of vendor code in js files.